# understanding logical operators and react rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

please help me in understanding this :
i am doing a conditional rendering in react-native something like this

```js
{state.sign && (<Image style={{height:200,width:100}} source{{uri:state.sign}})}
```

it renders with no issue  i have this  in stacknavigation  and when i try to navigate to the root with  navigation.popToTop()

this throws an error  . However when i change it to

```js
{ state.sign ? (<Image style={{height:200,width:100}} source{{uri:state.sign}}): null}
```

it works . there is something that i am not understanding. something where "&&" is continuously monitored and "?:" is  processed once and dusted?

Comment: It may help us to help you if you provide a more complete code example. What is being returned from the component? Please also include what the error is.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer. (What's the error?) But the `&&` and ternary will produce different results for the same value of `state.sign` in certain cases. The ternary will always return null if state.sign is falsy, whereas `&&` will evaluate to the value of `state.sign` (e.g. `undefined`, `false`, or `null`). IIRC, returning false or undefined makes React throw.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to close the tag?

```js
  <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part there's not much of a difference between the two, but one use case where it matters is when it's the return value of rendering. React components can render valid JSX, or `null` to indicate nothing is to be rendered, and booleans are ignored. Returning `undefined` isn't allowed.

[Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

#### Inline If with Logical `&&` Operator

This is used if you want to conditionally *include* some JSX with the rest of the rendered JSX.

Example

```
return (
  <>
    <h1>A Header</h1>
    <div>Some text on the page</div>
    {state.sign && (
      <Image
        style={{height: 200, width: 100}}
        source{{ uri:state.sign }}
      />
    )}
  </>
);
```

#### Inline If-Else with Ternary Operator

This is used if you want to conditionally render one JSX or another JSX along with the rest of the rendered JSX.

Example:

```
return (
  <>
    <h1>A Header</h1>
    <div>Some text on the page</div>
    {state.sign ? (
      <Image
        style={{height: 200, width: 100}}
        source{{ uri:state.sign }}
      />
    ) : (
      <div>There is nothing to see here!</div>
    )}
  </>
);
```

#### Preventing Component from rendering

In rare cases you might want a component to hide itself even though it was rendered by another component. To do this return `null` instead of its render output.

Here's where the difference matters if what you are trying to conditionally render ***is*** the return value of a component.

Invalid because it doesn't return `null` to render nothing:

```
return state.sign && (
  <Image
    style={{height: 200, width: 100}}
    source{{ uri:state.sign }}
  />
);
```

Valid:

```
return state.sign ? (
  <Image
    style={{height: 200, width: 100}}
    source{{ uri:state.sign }}
  />
) : null;
```